React-Select On change throws ' Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')' Error
I am just getting started with React and having difficulty in passing the value of the selected dropdown value to the backend. Sharing the code below for reference, any help would be highly appreciated.
On trying to select a value from dropdown, the following error is being thrown. My end goal is to pass the selected value to the backend on form submit
Error
 Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import Select from 'react-dropdown-select';
import axios from 'axios';

function App() {

  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [value, setValue] = useState([]);
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");

   const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert(value)
    console.log("Selected value:", value);
    axios.post("./getEmployeeData", {
      value,
    }).then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/listEmployees")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((employee) => {
        const parsed = JSON.parse(employee.employeeData);
        const employees = Object.entries(parsed).map(([key, value]) => ({
          label: value,
          value: value
        }));

        setData(employees);
        console.log(parsed, employees);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Select
          name="select"
          options={data}
          multi
          onChange={(option) => setValue(option.target.value)
        }
        />;

        <button type="submit"></button>
        <div className="message">{message ? <p>{message}</p> : null}</div>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;


According to the documentation, the signature of the onChange callback is (simplified) (newValue, actionMeta) => void. But your code isn't written that way, it's written as though you were using an HTML select. Instead: onChange={(newValue) => setValue(newValue)}. (I wouldn't use onChange={setValue} since the control passes two arguments to the callback, although I think state setters ignore all but the first argument.)

okay, updated the code. Now it sends [object, object] to the backend. How to pass the actual value?

It sounds like employees is an array of objects. You need to decide what property(ies) from those objects you want to send to the back-end. It may be clearer if you use a debugger to look at what's going on.

There is an error in your code, react-dropdown-select does not use  the same event handling as native HTML elements. The onChange handler receives the selected values directly, not an event.
you can use it like this
<Select
    name="select"
      options={data}
      multi
      onChange={(values) => setValue(values)
    }

Not the 'value' state has a list of value containing value and label you can extract, then send to api
